# Hive and sqoop Export inserting NULL values when the columns have values

Tags: hive, hiveql, sqoop, tbl-properties

Im facing some issues while exporting or making queries on hive.

I have a table while making a simple

```
select * from table where column1='12345';
```

The values shows up in 2 lines and many of the fields have null values.

While making this query. The column that shows with nulls now show with values:

```
select column1,column13,column300, column34 from table where column1='12345';
```

i already executed the queries on Ambari and using beeline but got the same weird behaviour.

Due to this, while im making the sqoop export to a postgres table is inserting null values on the columns.

Anyone knows what might cause this?

Comment: The second query is going to run as a map reduce job and the first query will be a simple fetch job. That is the difference between the two queries i can see

Comment: Try to run the first query with the limit clause and see if it's fetching expected result.